# Tooltip with position of the list element

Tags: plotting, tooltip

I want to use `Listplot` with `Tooltip`that displays `Position`of the element I'm hovering over.

```
data={{0,1},{1,3},{2,2}};
ListPlot[Tooltip[data]]
```

This is displaying the value of the element. Can I use the `Position`function in the tooltip?

Comment: `ListPlot[Tooltip[#, Position[data, #][[1, 1]]] & /@ data]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Map` and `MapIndexed` solutions are formally valid but `Thread` is often cleaner. (Poor guy is also underused, I believe.)

```
data = RandomInteger[10, {10, 2}];

ListPlot@Thread@Tooltip[#, Range@Length@#]&@data
```

Comment: Very Cool! Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 7):

```
data = Sort@RandomInteger[10, {10, 2}];
tts = {Directive[Red, 16, Bold], CellFrame -> 3, CellFrameMargins -> 5};

ListPlot[MapIndexed[Tooltip[#, First@#2, TooltipStyle -> tts] &, data],
         PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large], Frame -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]